# Use specific Android System WebView

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, package, chromium

I have installed on my android device (V 5.1.1) two package for Android System WebView:

- com.android.webview
- com.google.android.webview

I'm trying to use the second package, following different ways, deactivating or uninstalling (impossible) first, and now I want to force the second when I load my WebView directly by code.

Do you know any solutions?

PS: I know and in other cases, I'm used CustomTabs, but in this case, I can't Chrome or Chromium on my device.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Seems there is no way to change default WebView client without root on devices. Please check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139413/android-system-webview-installed-but-not-used-by-apps/139415#139415) answer.